# What is Virtual Processor core in AWS Ec2 and how to find it using Linux and Windows command

Tags: amazon-ec2

We are working on a project where we need to count licenses for JBoss EAP.
As per docs, it is based on virtual processor core for virtual machine but we need to know how it is captured in EC2 instances as we are trying to get license count on those machine.

Comment: Are you wanting to count the cores allocated to the virtual machine, or the total number of cores of the host computer (which hosts several virtual machines)?

Comment: Hi John, I want the first one However, I also wanted to know if virtual core and virtual processor core are same thing.

Comment: This might help: [Optimizing CPU Options - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-optimize-cpu.html)